# js/jquery form slides but not hiding in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my login page there are three forms,for Login,signup and pass reset.I wanted to show the login form only.and other two forms will appear if any user clicks the respective button.Every thing is doing fine in chrome.But in firefox the signup form always appears in the login page,but in the same time pass reset form is hiding there.My declaration of form properties are alright.I checked those.But I cant sort out the problem.

Here is the js code of hiding and slideup and fadein of forms :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var login = $('#loginform');
    var recover = $('#recoverform');
    var speed = 400;

    $('#to-recover').click(function () {
        $("#loginform").slideUp();
        $("#recoverform").fadeIn();
    });

    $('#to-login').click(function () {
        $("#recoverform").hide();
        $("#loginform").fadeIn();
    });

    $('#to-login').click(function () {

    });

    if ($.browser.msie == true && $.browser.version.slice(0, 3) < 10) {
        $('input[placeholder]').each(function () {

            var input = $(this);
            $(input).val(input.attr('placeholder'));

            $(input).focus(function () {
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                }
            });

            $(input).blur(function () {
                if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

and here is the css part

```
#loginbox form#loginform { z-index: 200; display:block;}
#loginbox form#recoverform { z-index: 100;     display:none;}
#loginbox form#recoverform .form-actions {    margin-top: 10px;}
#loginbox form#signupform { z-index: 150;     display:none;}
#loginbox form#signupform .form-actions {    margin-top: 10px;}
```

Can somebody please let me know where I am doing wrong.I think I did something wrong in css part,but chrome is showing perfectly thats why I am wondering.

Comment: This `#loginbox form#loginform` equals to `#loginform`, if you are using IDs in selectors then you shouldn't use selectors before them.
Also it is working for me in FF: http://jsfiddle.net/rS9QS/2/

Comment: the two form (login and pass reset) hides when I press button for sign up.But the sign up form is visible,when I load the  page (login.php).But with same coding the pass reset form is not visible.I just want to hide the sign up form when I go to the url of login.php

Comment: In your code you don't have signup button, but I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/rS9QS/3/
In this sample SignUp form is the default visible form and the other 2 has a button to show them.